# FormView CheckBox should fill Shipping info with Billing info

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Staying away from javascript I endeavor to use Check_Clicked event handler to populate my Shipping info if same as Billing info in my FormView. This should be real simple but I have not been able to get the plumbing right.

I am following the example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s78d0k1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#Y617 but would like to use my FormView instead of Form1.

The value that appears on checking the box is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

```
<asp:CheckBox id="SameCheckBox" AutoPostBack="True"
                    Text="Same as billing." TextAlign="Right"
                    OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" runat="server"/>


 protected void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox SameCheckBox = (CheckBox)FormView1.FindControl("SameCheckBox");
        TextBox BillingFirst = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("BillingFirstNameTextBox");
        TextBox ShippingFirst = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ShippingFirstNameTextBox");

        if (SameCheckBox.Checked)
        {    
            ShippingFirst.Text = BillingFirst.ToString();

        }
        else
            ShippingFirst = null;
    }
```

In addition to the solutions given to me below I will add for others edification; the other problem I had was DropdownList data. Here is what worked for me:

```
DropDownList BillingState = FormView1.Row.FindControl("BillingStateTextBox") as DropDownList;
DropDownList ShippingState = FormView1.Row.FindControl("ShippingStateTextBox")as DropDownList;
ShippingState.SelectedValue = BillingState.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
ShippingFirst.Text = BillingFirst.ToString();
```

Should be:

```
ShippingFirst.Text = BillingFirst.Text;
```

The `ToString()` output of a WebControl will be the type name.

Comment: **Wow**...you guys are fast. And thank you for the lesson. Of-course my formview now is functional.

Comment: @Marcle: I guess we deserve something for our answers :D

Comment: Tried to upvote...guess first time users don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Steve, ah apparently you need rep 15 to upvote :(  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-is-15-reputation-required-to-upvote

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
ShippingFirst.Text = BillingFirst.Text;
```

Comment: Whoops, I was a little too slow :)